# Error injector when register on module in angular

Tags: angularjs

I have register model as below :

```
var angularTest = angularTest || {};
angularTest.app = angular.module('angularTest', ['xPlat.service', 'xPlat.controller', 'xPlat.directives', 'xPlat.repository']).run(function (DB) {
    DB.init();
});
angular.module('xPlat.config', []);
angular.module('xPlat.directives', []);
angular.module('xPlat.controller', []);
angular.module('xPlat.service', []);
```

and I have a controller with the correct use (it's not error) as below :

```
angularTest.app.controller('logInController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.login = function () {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "http://localhost:4309/Account/Login",
            data: ""
        })
    }
}]);
```

but this controller below has error:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module("xPlat.controller", ['xPlat.service'])
        .controller('itemController', function ($scope, itemService) {
            // todo something

        });
})();
```

I want to change it like logInController as above. How do I change it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me when put into a single JS file. I'm assuming that you are not including the file that contains xPlat.controller in a  on your index.html page (or not including it if you are minifiying).

If you need more assistance, could you try to replicate it in a jsfiddle.